# no matching function for call to ‘std::exception::exception(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linux-mint

My project builds on Windows (vc++17) and I am new to Linux builds so I am not sure what is going on.

I created CMakeLists files for my project (with a C++17 requirement), generated the makefile, and then I used `make` to try build it on Linux. The error is:

```
/home/julien/source/zipfs/zipfs/include/zipfs/zipfs_assert.h:30:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::exception::exception(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   30 |   zipfs_usage_error_t(const char* message) : std::exception{ message } {}
      |                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/exception:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/new:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /home/julien/source/zipfs/zipfs/include/zipfs/zipfs_path_t.h:3,
                 from /home/julien/source/zipfs/zipfs/include/zipfs/zipfs_error_t.h:3,
                 from /home/julien/source/zipfs/zipfs/source/zipfs_error_t.cpp:1:
```

The incriminated code is:

```
zipfs_usage_error_t(const char* message) : std::exception{ message } {}
```

I don't see what is wrong with this; is it a c++ version mismatch ?

Comment: `std::exception` [does not provide a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) that accepts a `const char*` parameter.  If one exists on the Windows standard library you are using, it is a non-portable extension to the language.  There are [many derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) that could be used instead and do support this constructor.

Comment: Thanks. How would I construct the exception then, from a c-string?

Comment: You might want to inherit from `std::logic_error` or `std::runtime_error` which each provide a constructor taking a `const char*`

Comment: Thanks to you 2, I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::exception` [does not provide a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) that accepts a `const char*` parameter.

If one exists on the Windows standard library you are using, it is a non-portable extension to the language.

There are [many derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) that could be used as your base class instead, which do support this constructor.